# JFrame not printing properly

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jframe, jpanel

I am making a movie ticket management system. And for that, I want to generate a PDF. But the PDF is not making properly. When I set the visibility of my jframe true, I see that my jframe is updated properly. But when i generate PDF from that , it does not show me the updated value. It show me the default value in my PDF. How can I solve this?

Here I cannot show you all my code because of the limit of words in a post. In UserHistoryPanel.java, I want that when I pressed jButton1, PrintTicket jframe should be printed.

Here is my code:

UserHistoryPanel.java

```
package paneles;

import cambodia.raven.DateChooser;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class UserHistoryPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    String UserName, theatreName, theatreAddress;
    Integer UserId;
    /**
     * Creates new form UserHistoryPanel
     */
    public UserHistoryPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public UserHistoryPanel(String userName) {
        initComponents();
        UserName = userName;
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)HistoryTable.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);  
        show_history();
        jTextField1.setText("");
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int i = HistoryTable.getSelectedRow();
        TableModel model = HistoryTable.getModel();
        String OrderId = model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        String movieName = model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
        theatreName = model.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
        String hall = model.getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
        String date = model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
        String time = model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        find_theatreDeatils();
        new PrintTicket(OrderId,UserName, movieName, theatreName, hall, theatreAddress,  date,  time).setVisible(true);

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setJobName("Cineplex Management System");

        job.setPrintable(new Printable(){
        public int print(Graphics pg,PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
            if(pageNum>0){
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            g2.scale(1,1.1);

            JPanel jPanel1 = new PrintTicket().getjPanel1();
            jPanel1.paint(g2);        

            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;   
            }
        });

        boolean ok = job.printDialog();
        if(ok){
            try{ 
                job.print();
            }
            catch (PrinterException ex){
            }
        }
    }                                        



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTable HistoryTable;
    private cambodia.raven.DateChooser dateChooser1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

PrintTicket.java

```
package paneles;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PrintTicket extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form PrintTicket
     */
    public PrintTicket() {
        initComponents();
    }
    public PrintTicket(String OrderId,String UserName, String Movie, String Theatre, String Hall, String TheatreAddress, String Date, String Time) {
        initComponents();
        orderId.setText(OrderId);
        userName.setText(UserName);
        movie.setText(Movie);
        theatre.setText(Theatre);
        hall.setText(Hall);
        theatreAddress.setText(TheatreAddress);
        date.setText(Date);
        time.setText(Time);
    }

    public JPanel getjPanel1() {
        return jPanel1;
    }

    public void setjPanel1(JPanel jPanel1) {
        this.jPanel1 = jPanel1;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        date = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        orderId = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        userName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        movie = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        theatre = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        hall = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        theatreAddress = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        time = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(654, 723));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Ticket and Invoice");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Order Id:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Username:");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Movie:");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Theatre:");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Hall:");

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("Theatre Address:");

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("Date:");

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText("Time:");

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setText("Cineplex Mangement System");

        date.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        orderId.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        userName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        movie.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        theatre.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        hall.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        theatreAddress.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        time.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 58, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 572, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(userName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 390, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(movie, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(theatre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(orderId, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 177, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(hall, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 390, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(theatreAddress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(time, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 456, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(orderId, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(userName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(movie, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(theatre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(hall))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(theatreAddress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(time, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(45, 45, 45))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 720);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrintTicket.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrintTicket.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrintTicket.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrintTicket.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PrintTicket().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel date;
    private javax.swing.JLabel hall;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel movie;
    private javax.swing.JLabel orderId;
    private javax.swing.JLabel theatre;
    private javax.swing.JLabel theatreAddress;
    private javax.swing.JLabel time;
    private javax.swing.JLabel userName;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```